# Speedup by reducing number of for loops

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

I am currently coding using Matlab. As everyone knows, `for` loops are slow, while Matlab does matrix multiplication very efficiently. Unfortunately, my code is full of `for` loops.

My code resembles this:

```
function FInt = ComputeF(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H)
    %A is a real column vector of size [Na, 1].
    %B is a real column vector of size [Nb, 1].
    %C is a real column vector of size [Nc, 1].
    %D is a real column vector of size [Nd, 1].
    %E, F, G are real column vectors of the same size as A.
    %H is a real column vector of the same size as A.
    %This function evaluates FInt, a tensor of size [Na, Nb, Nc, Nd]. 

    %Recording the correct dimensions and initializing FInt
    Na = size(A, 1);
    Nb = size(B, 1);
    Nc = size(C, 1);
    Nd = size(D, 1);
    FInt = zeros(Na, Nb, Nc, Nd);

    %Computing the tensor FInt
    for na = 1:Na
        for nc=1:Nc
            for nd=1:Nd
                %Calculating intermediate values
                S1 = -((B(:) - C(nc) + E(na)) ./ (2 * sin(D(nd) ./ 2))).^2;
                S2 = (B(:) + C(nc) + F(na)) ./ (2 .* cos(D(nd) ./ 2));
                S3 = (B(:) + C(nc) + G(na)) ./ (2 .* cos(D(nd) ./ 2));
                S4 = H(na) ./ cos(D(nd) ./ 2);
                %Calculating the integrand FInt
                FInt(na, nc, :, nd) = exp(S1) .* (sinh(S2 + 1i * S4) + conj(sinh(S3 + 1i * S4)));
            end
        end
    end
end
```

As you can see I have already tried to vectorize the process by using `:` for the vector `B`, improving at least a bit the speed of computations. (Why `B`? Usually it is the longest vector).

My problem is that the quantities depend on so many indexes that I have no idea how to vectorize it properly.

Comment: Broadcast all your arrays at once, avoid all loops.

Comment: That being said, you use `nc` without defining it. You assign to index `nc` without looping over it. Could you please provide a working sample?

Comment: Your prose makes little sense. `:` is not used for `A`, which in fact does not appear anywhere. Commend says the output is `C` when it's actually `F`. This code is more of a mess the more I look at it. Please fix that.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. Could you please specify what you mean with broadcast?

Comment: Unit dimensions can be matched between multiple arrays.

Comment: 'Broadcasting' is a term used in Python `pandas`, but the MATLAB documentation just calls it [vectorization](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html).

Comment: @nekomatic. Sorry, that's the problem with being multilingual and switching rapidly

Comment: *As everyone knows for loops are really slow* - then everyone is often wrong, because the MATLAB compiler is actually often pretty good at optimising `for` loops. Is the performance of your code actually a problem?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, do you mean that if I define Vec1=[1;2] and Vec2=[1;2;3] then Vec1+Vec2 is well defined even though dimension do not match?

Comment: @nekomatic, When I use the profiler (in Matlab) I see that for large sizes of vectors A,B,C,D the time spent in computing this F is very long. I noticed that when I call this function in another routine then ComputeF takes approximately 70% of the time spent computing. I then (possibly falsely) deduced that the foor loops are the problems.

Comment: @G9MA. No, but `[1, 2] + [1; 2; 3]` is well defined because the result is clearly 3x2. You need to reshape your arrays so that the non-matching dimensions are in different slots.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I see what you mean... so for example if A is a vector of length Na and B is a vector of length Nb, then the result of (A+B) has dimension Na x Nb (considering a match of dimension like you did).  And to to be sure (A+B)(s,t) = A(s)+B(t) for suitable indexes s,t?

Comment: @G9MA. Sounds like you got it. I posted an answer with a link I really think you should read. It's the official-ish intro, and really explains it well, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In numpy, there is an idea that is formally called broadcasting. MATLAB introduced the concept in R2016b. It is called "vectorization", "expansion", and sometimes "broadcasting" in the MATLAB community. The idea is that if you line up the dimensions of a bunch of arrays, you can expand unit dimensions to match the full ones. Here is a great resource on the subject: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/.

If you want your result to have size `[Na, Nb, Nc, Nd]`, you can make all your arrays of the appropriate size, with ones filling in the missing dimensions:

```
A = reshape(A, Na, 1, 1, 1);
B = reshape(B, 1, Nb, 1, 1);
C = reshape(C, 1, 1, Nc, 1);
D = reshape(D, 1, 1, 1, Nd);
E = reshape(E, Na, 1, 1, 1);
F = reshape(F, Na, 1, 1, 1);
G = reshape(G, Na, 1, 1, 1);
H = reshape(H, Na, 1, 1, 1);
```

Now you can perform vectorized operations on these arrays directly with no ambiguity:

```
S1 = -((B - C + E) ./ (2 * sin(D ./ 2))).^2;
S2 = (B + C + F) ./ (2 .* cos(D ./ 2));
S3 = (B + C + G) ./ (2 .* cos(D ./ 2));
S4 = H ./ cos(D ./ 2);
%Calculating the integrand F
FInt = exp(S1) .* (sinh(S2 + 1i * S4) + conj(sinh(S3 + 1i * S4)));
```

Notice that all the explicit loops were removed here. The sizes of the intermediate arrays depend on the sizes of their inputs:

```
size(S1) == [Na, Nb, Nc, Nd]
size(S2) == [Na, Nb, Nc, Nd]
size(S3) == [Na, Nb, Nc, Nd]
size(S4) == [Na, 1, 1, Nd]
```

You don't need to preallocate the output because it automatically results from the sizes of the inputs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Your explanations are cristal clear. I think I really got it now.

Comment: @G9MA. I'm glad it worked out for you.